# SUMIFS on a date column without using a helper column

Tags: excel, sumifs

Example data:

[image]

I want to sum everything in column B if its year in column A is 2023. I don't want to add a year column in column C. Instead, I'd like to write a `SUMIFS` that somehow examines the year dynamically, within the formula itself. Is this possible?

I will note that `=sumifs(B:B,YEAR(A:A),2023)` did not work, unsurprisingly.

Comment: Formula you provided doesn't work because you try to pass array (YEAR(A:A)) while only range can be accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be better to use <kbd>SUM()</kbd> or <kbd>SUMPRODUCT()</kbd> based on ones Excels Version.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>D2</kbd>

```
=SUM((YEAR(A2:A3)=2023)*B2:B3)
```

---

Also it is highly suggested to use `Structured References` when you are not sure about the last row of your data, since taking the whole blank ranges will reasonably slow down the Excel functionality, since it will iterate through the blank/empty cells as well.

---

Comment: A little nitpicking: you mean "one's Excel version" and "recommended" feels kind of closer than *"highly suggested"*. Also, `=SUM((YEAR(Table1[Date])=2023)*Table1[Amt])` would be a nice addition.

Comment: @VBasic2008 Sir, agree with you on that, highly suggested because of the speed, accuracy and the efficiency.

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya can we use multiple criteria here? If we wanted year = 2023 and month = 5, does this solution allow for that?

Comment: @JosephErickson nope, also since as per your OP you specifically needed the same for the `Year` and not month and year wise, however we can modify the same to achieve it. That said the formula will be `=SUM((YEAR(A2:A3)=2023)*(MONTH(A2:A3)=5)*B2:B3)` i would highly suggest to use cell reference for the year and month criteria like it will be `=SUM((YEAR(A2:A3)=H2)*(MONTH(A2:A3)=H1)*B2:B3)` where `H1` is `5` and `H2` is `2023` which you can change and make it work dynamically

Answer (score 3):

If you specifically want to use `SUMIFS`:

```
=SUMIFS(B2:B3,A2:A3,">="&DATE(2023,1,1),A2:A3,"<"&DATE(2024,1,1))
```

Result:

[image]